# TYPO3 ver. 6.2.2 Bootstrap 3 News - TOP3 and pagination

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typo3, typoscript

Have for some time now played with the new TYPO3 ver. 6.2.2 with the Bootstrap 3.
and WOW its easy...

I have some questions about the News setup.

1. Show top 3 news.
   If I have a page, and here I "Add a new record..." then I can add a "Special Elements" and here I can add the "Special Menus".
   I can then in the "Menu and sitemap" add a menu type = "Display subpages as news entries" and then select the page ID I want to show subpages from..
   My question is now, is I possible to only show the latest 3-5 subpages/news ?
2. Show 5 news on each site/page.
   I can see that the Bootstrap allow me to use pagination code, how can I add it so I can select that if i have 15 news/subpages, then i want to show 5 on each page, thats = 3 pages ?
3. Where do it save the template for the "Display subpages as news entries" so I can edit the layout and is it possible to duplicate the template with another name, and then tell the page, that it need to use that "custom made" template on this page and the original on another page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

glad you like it.

1.
This is currently just an example how you could display news without any extension in typo3 but feel free to make an Feature request in the repository of the package. https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/issues?state=open

2.
The default setting of the package is 5 so it will display the pagination when you have more than 5 pages to show you can adjust the settings in the template section of your root page -> template / constant editor / category -> bootstrap_package: Basic

3.
the example is completly based on typoscript its an advanced example and is build ontop the normal text with image rendering - the setup for this you can find here https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/blob/master/Configuration/ContentElements/Base.ts from line 797 to 1062

to make a custom menu you need at first to register a custom type in your PageTS

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.menu_type.addItems.TYPENAME = My Custom Menu
```

after that you can create the typoscript setup for your menu rendering

```
tt_content.menu.20 {
    TYPENAME < .default
}
```